# How to make a stacklayout appear from the ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Right now i have a `calendar` which is : https://github.com/lubiepomaranczki/XamForms.Controls.Calendar, if i click on the day and there's data for this day, it lists the data for this day like that :

[[image: 15 july clicked1]

My problem is that i don't know how to go from ViewModel to code behind to tell him to switch the IsVisible value to true. I never faced this problem, usually we just send data from the UI to ViewModel.

Thanks for help.

**If i click `a date with no value`, i want to make this stacklayout which is from CalendarPage.xaml `visible`:**

```
        <StackLayout IsVisible="false" x:Name="PlusIconStackLayout">
            <ImageButton Source="iconplus.png"  HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"></ImageButton>
        </StackLayout>
```

**In my CalendarPageViewModel.cs i already have a command that checks if if the TasksGroup exist or not and load the data if it does.**

```
public ICommand DateChosen => new Command((obj) =>
{
    var dateChosen = obj as DateTime?;

    if (dateChosen != null)
    {

        tasksGroup = App.Database.GetTaskGroupByDate(dateChosen.Value).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (tasksGroup != null)
        {

            var data = App.Database.GetTaskByGroupId(TasksGroup.ID).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            TasksGroup = tasksGroup;
            TasksGroup.Taches = data;
            TasksGroup.ExpositionResult = Helper.CalculateExposition(TasksGroup);
            ExpositionResult = TasksGroup.ExpositionResult;

            Tasks = new ObservableCollection<Tasks>(data);
            TasksGroup.Taches.ForEach(x =>
            {
                TaskDBA = x.TaskDBA;
                TaskDuration = x.TaskDuration;
                TaskDescription = x.TaskDescription;
            });

        }
        else
        {
            Tasks = null;
            TasksGroup = null;
            ExpositionResult = null;
        }
    }

});
```

**In the CalendarPage.xaml.cs i have a DateClicked function that i could use but i am unsure how to link it based on VewModel result**

```
public void DateClicked(object sender, DateTime e)
{
    PlusIconStackLayout.IsVisible = true;

}
```

Comment: why don't you just bind `IsVisible` to a property on your VM?

Comment: @Jason Could you post a snippet to give me an idea because i am not sure that i am following ( i'm really visual haha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i don't know how to go from ViewModel to code behind to tell him to
> switch the IsVisible value to true.

You don't need to do this.  If you want to control the value of a UI property from the ViewModel, use data binding to do it.  You don't need to do anything in the code-behind

```
<StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding SomeBoolProperty}" x:Name="PlusIconStackLayout">
  <ImageButton Source="iconplus.png"  HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"></ImageButton>
</StackLayout>
```

then in your VM, create a property (be sure to use INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
public bool SomeBoolProperty { ... }
```

and whenever you need to toggle the visibility of that UI, just set the appropriate value of the property